# Video player in android programming

Tags: android

Hi I wanna make a application by eclipse and I need to pause a Clip in a special time for example I wanna pause a clip in 2:30 and i don't know how can I do that please help me

Comment: What exactly do you have at the moment? This will get downvoted quickly if you don't improve the question. Please take a look at the how to ask section.

Comment: What is an 'eclipse'?

Comment: Don't make questions that asks how i can do this or that, ask specific questions with code you have try and didn't want and give the result you expect

Answer (score 0):

Add following

```
videoView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    videoView.pause();

}
}, 150000);
```